# Lambda calculus, $M$ doesn't have a normal form, $N$ has normal form. Find $M N$ that has a normal form?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to understand more about $\lambda$-calculus through exercises so I'm stuck with this one:

Being:

- $M$ a $\lambda$-term without normal form (we can't find a normal form, such as the term  $(\lambda x. x x) (\lambda x. x x)$), and
- $N$ a $\lambda$-term with a normal form.

Can we find an expression such as

$$(M N)$$

that has a normal form?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(\lambda f.f\,A)(K B)$, where $A$ is any $\lambda$-term with no normal form (e.g., $(\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x)$), $K$ is the $K$-combinator ($\lambda x .\lambda y. x$) and $B$ is any normal form $\lambda$-term, (e.g., $\lambda x.x$). Then $(\lambda f.f\,A)$ has no normal form, but if you choose the leftmost $\beta$-redex at each step you have:

$$
(\lambda f.f\,A)(K B) \rightsquigarrow K B A \rightsquigarrow B
$$

So $B$ is a normal form for $(\lambda f.f\,A)(K B)$.

Comment: Now I see, thanks!