# SKI combinatory calculus, $M$ doesn't have a normal form. Find $(M S)$ that has a normal form

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

The problem is related to a similar [question about lambda calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719312/lambda-calculus-m-doesnt-have-a-normal-form-n-has-normal-form-find-m-n).

This question is about SKI combinatory calculus. I want to find a term $M$ *without* a normal form that will yield a term *with* a normal form after application with the $S$ combinator: $$(M S)\text{ should reduce to a normal form}$$

Since every term of lambda calculus can be translated to a SKI term, one can also assume that $M$ is a lambda calculus term.

For example: If the right hand side of the application was the $K$ combinator, one can construct $M$ using the translation of the lambda calculus term $\lambda x.((x I) \Omega)$, where $(K I)$ will then result in $\lambda x.\lambda y.y$, and therefore $((K I)\Omega)$ yields $I$.

I was not able to find a similar example for the $S$ combinator (or $I$, but I mainly care about $S$). Can such a term even exist and if not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer. I definitely didn't think about the problem long enough, sorry. Maybe this helps someone else though.

Let $M=\lambda x.((((x I) I) \lambda x.\lambda y.I) \Omega)$, then $((SI)I)\leadsto\omega$ and $(\omega\lambda x.\lambda y.I)\leadsto\lambda x.I$. Now we have the same situation as the example in my question, ultimately reducing the term to $I$.

Comment: It's expressly allowed to answer your own question, so no need to apologize.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just felt stupid that I found the answer so quickly after I thought I couldn't solve it; I guess that's the magic of stackexchange.